# Закрывать ли придаточное со "что"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, придаточное-предложение

К своему стыду не могу разобраться с простым случаем:

*Философы утверждают, что предметы не существуют(,) или что-то в этом роде.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Союз "или" соединяет здесь *неоднородные* конструкции: *придаточное предложение* и *номинативный оборот*, который не включен в это придаточное, а напрямую связан с главным (утверждают *то-то*). Т. е. придаточное предложение находится **внутри главного**, и на общих основаниях его нужно обособить, поставив *запятую*.

Пунктуация без второй запятой была бы в случае *однородных* конструкций, напр. двух придаточных (утверждают, что А или что В) или двух номинативных оборотов:

> Философы вечно утверждают *что им вздумается* или *что-нибудь не
> поддающееся проверке*.

Comment: Браво! Спасибо, Александр! Было ощущение, что запятую надо всё-таки поставить, но не спешил поправить отправленное сообщение — не дай Бог оказалось бы, что всё-таки она не нужна.

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта возможны:

(1) *Философы утверждают, что предметы не существуют или что-то в этом роде.*

(2) *Философы утверждают, что предметы не существуют,  или что-то в этом роде.*

Союз ИЛИ можно считать **одиночным разделительным союзом**, тогда запятая не ставится. При этом союз может соединять **придаточное предложение и член предложения.**

Если считать союз ИЛИ **присоединительным**, то пауза делается и запятая ставится.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса без запятой:

Мадам… кокетливо сообщила, что Асеньки сегодня не будет, ей нужно пораньше забрать сына из детского сада **или что-то в этом роде.** [Нина Катерли. Дневник сломанной куклы // «Звезда», 2001]

Кажется, они считали, что ворвань предохраняет от холода **или что-то в этом роде**. [В. П. Катаев. Новогодний рассказ (1947)]

Мол, не надо делать плохо людям или **что-то в этом роде»**, ― заметил М. Касьянов. [Банковские новости // «Финансы и кредит», 2003.02.17]

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Вот как! И за примеры спасибо!

Comment: @Sharon Думаю, что решение здесь зависит от желаемого **смысла** высказывания (классификация союза вторична и зависит от выбора этого смысла). В нашем примере с запятой смысл таков: одни философы утверждают, что предметы не существуют, другие утверждают нечто близкое к этому (говорящий относит различия в формулировке на счет философов). Если же запятая не ставится, то присоединение происходит к придаточному предложению (возникают новые **его члены**).

Comment: Тогда говорящий приписывает высказывание всем философам скопом, но при этом подразумевает возможную неточность своего понимания где-то услышанного (либо свою забывчивость, нежелание вникать и т. п.). Такой вариант возможен, но вне дополнительного контекста мне показался более естественным вариант _уверенного_ высказывания в начале какого-то рассуждения.

Comment: Грамматика – это формальная наука,  ей не стоит приписывать те возможности, которыми она не обладает.  Грамматика разрешает нам соединить союзом И слово и придаточное предложение, также она предоставляет возможность выбора между соединительным союзом и присоединительным.   Пауза в речи, запятая на письме – вот что мы воспринимаем из сказанного,  на подробный грамматический анализ  наше восприятие  не рассчитано. Я полагаю, что при отсутствии паузы и запятой говорящий сразу сообщает, что его высказывание неточное,  а при постановке запятой он говорит об этом в добавочном сообщении.

Comment: Получается разное оформление речи. В чем разница?  Вариант с запятой выглядит выразительнее, эмоциональнее, интереснее, значительнее.  Он самодостаточен, в то время как  при отсутствии запятой фраза кажется незаконченной и требует продолжения, то есть это как бы  только как часть высказывания.